# Autoincrement indexing after groupby with pandas on the original table

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I cannot solve a very easy/simple problem in pandas. :(

I have the following table:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=dict(a=[1, 1, 1,2, 2, 3,1], b=["A", "A","B","A", "B", "A","A"]))
df

Out[96]: 
   a  b
0  1  A
1  1  A
2  1  B
3  2  A
4  2  B
5  3  A
6  1  A
```

I would like to make an incrementing ID of each grouped (grouped by columns a and b) unique item. So the result would like like this (column c):

```
Out[98]: 
   a  b  c
0  1  A  1
1  1  A  1
2  1  B  2
3  2  A  3
4  2  B  4
5  3  A  5
6  1  A  1
```

I tried with:

```
df.groupby(["a", "b"]).nunique().cumsum().reset_index()
```

Result:

```
Out[105]: 
   a  b  c
0  1  A  1
1  1  B  2
2  2  A  3
3  2  B  4
4  3  A  5
```

Unfortunatelly this works only for the grouped by dataset and not on the original dataset. As you can see in the original table I have 7 rows and the grouped by returns only 5.

So could someone please help me on how to get the desired table:

```
   a  b  c
0  1  A  1
1  1  A  1
2  1  B  2
3  2  A  3
4  2  B  4
5  3  A  5
6  1  A  1
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### `groupby` + `ngroup`

```
df['c'] = df.groupby(['a', 'b']).ngroup() + 1
```

---

```
   a  b  c
0  1  A  1
1  1  A  1
2  1  B  2
3  2  A  3
4  2  B  4
5  3  A  5
6  1  A  1
```

Comment: This is exactly what my looking for! Thank you!

Comment: OMG! `ngroup` is what I've always been looking for!!

Comment: @richardec Its a nice handy function :-)

Answer (score 2):

Use [`pd.factorize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.factorize.html) after create a tuple from `(a, b)` columns:

```
df['c'] = pd.factorize(df[['a', 'b']].apply(tuple, axis=1))[0] + 1
print(df)

# Output
   a  b  c
0  1  A  1
1  1  A  1
2  1  B  2
3  2  A  3
4  2  B  4
5  3  A  5
6  1  A  1
```

Comment: Did you know about `ngroup`?

Comment: Yes but I never use it :)

Comment: Hmm. It seems really useful.